# Coldfusion regex substring YouTube ID

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm trying to pull a youtube ID from a link like this;

```
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/OZ3jyvM0jZc/2.jpg" alt="" />
```

I've only been successful in taking out the ID, but not actually getting it!

```
<cfset ytID = '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/0Z3jyvM0jZc/2.jpg" alt="" />' />
#reReplace(referer,"(vi=?(\=|\/))([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)|(vi=\/)([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)", "\1", "one")#


Output: <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi//2.jpg" alt="" />
```

RegEx is not my friend today.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Regex is not my forte. But why not use reMatch() or reFind() instead?

Comment: Would those do the same thing?

Comment: @Nate - Same? No. But they are similar (find versus replace) and would seem more logical since you want to *find* the value not replace it. See if @Satyajit's example does the trick.

Comment: True, true.  I need to actually replace it with a YT video as the code doesn't come in over RSS.

Comment: @Nate - What is an example of the desired output?

Comment: Just the ID in the link; 0Z3jyvM0jZc

Comment: @Nate - Then try @Satyajit's example. (I cannot comment on the regex ;), but the idea is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try with regex:

```
vi\/([^\/]+) // 0Z3jyvM0jZc
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape the forward slashes in CFML regex patterns. So take what The Mask has and use whichever method you prefer (both of these only work if the string is indeed a match):

```
<cfset ytID = '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/0Z3jyvM0jZc/2.jpg" alt="" />'>

<cfoutput>
<pre>
    <cfset sLenPos=REFind("/vi/([^/]+)", ytID, 1, "True")>
    #mid(ytID, sLenPos.pos[2], sLenPos.len[2])# == OZ3jyvM0jZc

    #reReplace(ytID,".*/vi/([^/]+)/.*", "\1")# == OZ3jyvM0jZc
</pre>
</cfoutput>
```

The key to keeping this simple is using the `[^/]+` to match one or more characters that aren't `/`

Answer (score 1):

I think regex might be the wrong tool for this job. How about using lists?

```
 <cfset ytStr = '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/0Z3jyvM0jZc/2.jpg" alt="" />'>
 <cfset ytID = ListGetAt(ytStr, 4, '/')>
```

Comment: If the "id" is always in the same position, then yes, list functions are simpler. Otherwise, regex has the edge. @Nate - Is the position static?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <cfset ytID = '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/0Z3jyvM0jZc/2.jpg" alt="" />'>
    <cfset sLenPos=REFind("(vi=?(\=|\/))([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)|(vi=\/)([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)", ytID, 1, "True")>
<cfoutput>
    #mid(ytID, sLenPos.pos[1], sLenPos.len[1])#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Yeah all those regex groups! Try with regex "vi=?[\=|\/]([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)|vi=\/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)"